# python select which module to use for a function?

Tags: python, python-decorators

```py
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp

def sum(x):
    xp = cp if isinstance(x, cp.ndarray) else np
    return xp.sum(x)
```

As above, notice inside the function there is `xp`, I'd like it to be `numpy` if the input `x` is a numpy array; and be `cupy` if `x` is a `cupy` array. I'd like to write it in a decorator `dispatch(x)` to look neater. Is there a way to do it? Thanks!

**update**
what I've tried:

```py
def dispatch(func):
    def wrapper(x):
        global xp
        xp = cp if x.__class__ is cp.ndarray else np
        return func(x) 
    return wrapper
```

The above works fine, but I'd like it to take in an argument `arg` and choose `cp` or `np` based on `arg` instead of `x`, since in my use case the input `x` can either be an array, or a class whose `cls.data` is an array.

How it should be used:

```py
@dispatch(arg=x.data)
def sum(x):
    return xp.sum(x)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code for the decorator you have tried.

Comment: Ok. I see your update. Could you just define two decorators?

Comment: how to do that? I'm quite new to decorators and still confused

Comment: I mean use your existing: `def dispatch(func):` as you have now, plus `def dispatch_data(func):` which uses `x.data.__class__` internally.

Comment: Yep that's on way. Thanks! Any possibilities that they can be combined?

Comment: Ok, but looking at your question again, do you mean that when calling your `sum()` function, the call site could provide one of four different types of parameter: Where the variable itself could be `cp` or `np`, or the variable has a `data` attribute which could be either `cp` or `np`?